# AWS Key Pair Lost how to Recover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, aws-cli

- I have lost EC2 Instance key pair and can't i download it again from AWS Management console.?
- Please advise how i can connect the same instance again with easiest way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to recover a lost keypair.  In addition to the suggestion from @E.J. Brennan, there is another way to get access to your instance without recreating it via a snapshot.

Stop the instance, and disassociate the boot disk from the instance.  You can then associate the volume with another instance, mount it, and you have access to the file system.

Update the authorized_keys in /home/ec2-user/.ssh, and then revert the steps - disassociate from the temporary instance, associate it with the original instance, then restart the original.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no way to recover a lost keypair. Amazon, even if they could, won't give it to you again.

If you still have access to the aws console, you could create a snapshot of the running instance and bring up a new instance from that snapshot and assign it a new keypair - and this time make a few copies and store it in a few safe places.

Comment: True. AWS does not keep a copy of your private key so they are unable to provide a copy to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate a public key from your private key, if you have it available with you:

```sh
ssh-keygen -f "your-private-key.pem" -y > "newPublicKey.pem"
```

After the new key is generated, open in an editor, and copy the content.

Go to AWS console → EC2 Console → Key Pair → Import key-pair.

In the option, use the name of the lost key, and paste the public key data that you copied.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this **without** disassembling the instance, which is the only way that has worked for me:

**1-** create another key-pair either in the instance using ssh-keygen or using putty (if you use putty, use putty gen to create a ppk file)

**2-** use the pem file to create a ppk file (which has a public part and private part of the key)

**3-** access the instance via EC2 instance connect inside AWS

**4-** access the file .ssh/authorized_keys using vim and add or replace the content with the following content:
ssh-rsa ppk_public_part pem_filename_without_extension

**5-** save the authorized_keys file

**6-** test the access with the pem file from your machine

**Important**: You still have to make sure that the security group allows access to the instance via your IP and port 22 to use SSH properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you've lost your private key, unfortunately you cannot get it back. You can however access your instance, create a new private/public keypair, and store this new public key in your .ssh directory. Here are some options to login:

**EC2 Instance Connect** (supported on Amazon Linux 2 2.0.20190618+, or Ubuntu 20.04+):

As of ~2019, you can connect to an instance within the Management Console by using EC2 Instance Connect. Just supply a username and wala! You will need to have port 22 open.

**Sessions Manager** (supported operating systems listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/operating-systems-and-machine-types.html):

Another option you can use is Sessions Manager. For this, you do not need port 22 to be open. You only need to apply an IAM role to your instance with the AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore managed policy attached.

Both options are also available on the AWS CLI, using either command:

`aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id <your_instance_id>`

`aws ssm start-session --target <your_instance_id>`

You will need the Sessions Manager Plugin for the CLI if you wish to use SSM (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html)

Hope this helps!